# java for and while cycles with very slow speed while processing bigger data from database

Tags: java

I have this java code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;    
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBresult {
    int countColumns;
    public ArrayList<String> columnLabels;
    public ArrayList<String[]> rows;
    public ArrayList<String> primaryKeys;
    public ArrayList<String> tablenameByColum;

    public static DBresult build(ResultSet set) throws SQLException {
        DBresult result = new DBresult();
        result.countColumns = set.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        result.rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        result.columnLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.tablenameByColum = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] row;
        while (set.next()) {
            row = new String[result.countColumns];
            for (int i = 1; i <= result.countColumns; i++) {
                row[i-1] = set.getString(i);
            }
            result.rows.add(row);
        }
        ResultSetMetaData meta = set.getMetaData();
        for (int i = 1; i <= result.countColumns; i++) {
            result.columnLabels.add(meta.getColumnLabel(i));
            result.tablenameByColum.add(meta.getTableName(i));
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        try {
            return new Gson().toJson(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static DBresult fromString(String json){
        try {
            return new Gson().fromJson(json, DBresult.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

generated result by this java code looks like this, e.g.:

```
{"result":{"countColumns":4,"columnLabels":["NAME","ID","IDSECOND","TIME"],"rows":[["Myname","1399675811417","1424733576894","1425215413292"],["Yurname","1399675811417","1438639227874","1497342014341"],...],"tablenameByColum":["NAMES","NAMES","NAMES","NAMES"]},"ID":0,"errors":[]}
```

Problem happens when I need to process bigger data (thousands entries), it is **veeeery slow**,  takes about minute(s) and more to finish. Any idea how to reduce processing time please?

Similar code in php:

```
$result = dibi::query(' 
    SELECT `NAME`,
    `ID`,
    `IDSECOND`,
    `TIME`
    FROM `NAMES`;');
$value = $result->fetchAll();
$data = '';
foreach ($value as $item)
{
    $data = $data . '["'.$item->NAME.'","'.$item->ID.'","'.$item->IDSECOND.'","'.$item->TIME.'"],';
} 
$data = substr($data, 0, -1);
$data='['.$data.']';
```

In php I am able to reduce it like this:

```
foreach ($value as $item)
{
    $array[] = '["'.$item->NAME.'","'.$item->ID.'","'.$item->IDSECOND.'","'.$item->TIME.'"]';
} 
$array = implode(",", $array);
$data='['.$array.']';
```

But now I would like to improve java code to be more efficient. I don't know java, so any help for newbie is highly appreciated. Many thanks :)

Comment: Which part is slow?  Perhaps each `set.next()` could be processed in its own thread, and merge the results when all complete.

Comment: I bet the bottleneck is serializing to JSON. Have you measured how long it takes each step? (step1 = query, step2 = fill `DBResult`, step3 = serialize to JSON)